# FirefoxDriver do not launch any URL and perform any action

Tags: java, linux, selenium, webdriver, geckodriver

I have started a clear CentOS with Eclipse Neon, newest Selenium 3.7.1 and Firefox 52.4. 
I'm trying to invoke any URL but Firefox starts and do nothing. I do not have any proxy.

I was trying to starts Firefox with default page like this:

```
FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
fp.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage", URL);
fp.setPreference("startup.homepage_welcome_url", URL);
fp.setPreference("startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional", URL);
```

it worked, but just page has been opened, nothing more.

It is common problem? How can i fix this?

Comment: Can you provide some additional code? What actions are you performing on the FirefoxDriver?

Comment: For instance just login test:

        driver.findElement(By.id("main_form:nazwa")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.id("main_form:nazwa")).sendKeys(LOGIN);
     driver.findElement(By.id("main_form:haslo")).click();
       driver.findElement(By.id("main_form:haslo")).sendKeys(PASSWORD);
        driver.findElement(By.name("main_form:j_idt25")).click();

I want to perform any action, nothing works and I have to use some kind of workaround to get to the main page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned of using `Selenium 3.7.1 and Firefox 52.4`.

Release Notes of **`GeckoDriver`** clearly mentions that :

> **`Note that with geckodriver 0.19.0 the following versions are recommended: - Firefox 55.0 (and greater) - Selenium 3.5 (and greater)`**

So as you are using, **`Selenium 3.7.1`** you mustn't be using below **`geckodriver 0.19.0`**. Hence your solution would be to bump up your **`Firefox`** to **`v56.x`** level.

Comment: It works! Upgrading the firefox version from official site (not from package repo where 52.x was the newest) solved the problem. 
Warm thank You and have a nice day : )